# remove last two parameters from URL

Tags: javascript, string

i want to break a following url

> http://www.example.com?name=john&token=3425kkhh34l4345jjjhjhj&uid=09900434&cn=bella&cjid=3344324

into this by eliminating last two parametes i.e. ***&cn=bella&cjid=3344324***

> http://www.example.com?name=john&token=3425kkhh34l4345jjjhjhj&uid=09900434

the length of the url may change but the last two parameters remains in that position only. so how can i remove that in a efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A RegExp is the easiest way for this case:

```
str = str.replace(/&[^&]*&[^&]*$/,'');
```

Comment: +1 for a quick n working ans , can you please explain the expression

Comment: @Hunt `[^&]*` means: Match any consecutive non-`&`-character. `&` matches a literal `&`. `$` matches the end of a string. Combined, you get: `& <any non-& character> & <any non-& character> <end of string>` (= RegEx in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace with regular expression. If the url is in var url then you can use this one

```
var new_url = url.replace(/&cn=.*/, '');
```

you can test it with

```
var url = 'http:\www.example.com?name=john&token=3425kkhh34l4345jjjhjhj&uid=09900434&cn=bella&cjid=3344324';
console.info(url.replace(/&cn=.*/, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "http://dom.com/?one=1&two=2&three=3&four=4";

string.match(/(.*)&(.*)&(.*)/)[1]; // strips last two parameters
```

Comment: I prefer `replace`, because your code *can* throw an error, when the string does not match the pattern (`null[1]`: "TypeError: null has no properties").

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to replace the last 2 parameters with the empty string:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3&p4=4";
var urlWithoutLast2Parameters = url.replace(/&[^&]+&[^&]+$/,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function IndexOf to find the location of the '&cn' and then just use the substring function to create a new string eliminating the '&cn' portion of the URL, so something like...

var intIndexOf = str.IndexOf('&cn=')

strURL = strURL.substring(0,intCharAt)